# Nerve endings on the skin

Tags: neuroscience

We can perceive sensation of pain if we are poked on any part of the skin.  Does this mean there is a nerve ending at every point on the skin?

Does this also mean that each of these nerves go all the way to the brain as single strands so that the brain can distinguish between the touch at any two distinct locations?

Comment: Could you? I don't believe you can. Try blindfolding yourself, have a friend poke you with a sharp pencil, then you try and mark the *exact* spot (after the pencil has been removed) with an ink pen or Sharpie, then have the friend tell you how close you were, or take an image before the pencil indentation fades.

Comment: Testing this is a common experiment given to public-school children; described [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/chtouch.html) for example.  As that link shows, threshold distances vary widely over the body, with few regions being remotely as sensitive as the question asks.  Since the premise of the question is shaky, you may want to revise it to focus on the question you want answered.

Comment: @MattDMo - Hope the question is now valid